# mobx UseObserver not re-rendering on store update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to create a simple react app Using MobX, TypeScript and React Hooks, where I will type a name of a city, and on clicking an **add** button, it will update the list of the cities in the UI with the newly added city.

**[CodeSandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-react-mob-hooks-qj0fe?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

The problem is, the list is not getting updated when i click the add button with a new name of a city.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Don't use `useLocalStore` (`context.tsx`) for creating the store, create the store by directly calling the store function, and wrap the return value of `createStore` function (`store.ts`)  in an `observable`

```
  // context.tsx
  // const store = useLocalStore(createStore);
  const store = createStore()
```

```
// store.ts
import { observable } from "mobx";

export const createStore = () => {
  const store = observable({
    Cities: ["Gotham"],

    get allCities(): Array<string> {
      return store.Cities;
    },
    get cityCount(): Number {
      return store.Cities.length;
    },
    addCity: (city: string) => {
      console.log("store: adding city: " + city);
      store.Cities.push(city);
      console.log(store.Cities);
    }
  });

  return store;
};

export type TStore = ReturnType<typeof createStore>;
```

2. The return value of your `CityView` component needs to be wrapped in the `useObserver` function from `mobx-react-lite`

```
// city.tsx
import { useObserver } from "mobx-react-lite";

export const CityView: React.FC<{ cities: string[] }> = ({ cities }) => {
  return useObserver(() => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {cities.map((city: string) => (
          <li key={city}>{city}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  });
};
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-react-mob-hooks-s2zbg)